# Best way to lower the resolution to an image

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an application in which I run heavy algorithms on a photograph. The user uses his cellphone to take a photo, the photo is dynamic. Then I use a plugin for the user can cut his face in a square. This is a size of `280px x 280px,` and a new image of this size is generated.

I do not know much about the subject but they tell me that I must lower the resolution of the image to optimize the execution times of the algorithm, since in a cellular the procedure that I need is delayed a little more. I have this code that is not mine, and I need to reduce the size of the image to optimize the time it takes to execute an algorithm, but without distorting or pixelating the image.

How can I do it?
I need to have an image of 280px x 280 px, but without losing quality. I need to optimize it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmae5p23/

```
var w = 200,
    h = 200,
    p = 50,
    q = 50;

var img = $("img").get(0);

img.onload = function() {
    cv.width = p;
    cv.height = q;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, p, q);

    cv.style.width = w + "px";
    cv.style.height = h + "px";
};

img.src = "https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/FORD_FOCU_2012-1.png";
```

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/xmae5p23/1/ ? though, your code makes no mention of 280x280, only 200x200, but the principal remains

Comment: @JaromandaX With that, the image is optimized?

Comment: Re-reading your original code, it looks like you want to scale the image to 50x50, then to 200x200?

Comment: @JaromandaX That code is not mine, how I told you I just need to optimize it, I would appreciate it if you can help me with that. I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You scale the image down to `50px` by `50px` using JavaScript, and then use CSS to scale it back up to `200px` by `200px`. What?

I have simplified you code a bit. It now no longer takes `p` and `q` parameters, and simply scales the image to `w` and `h` using JavaScript. I have also removed the code that scaled the image using CSS, as it was redundant.

```js
var cv = $("#cv").get(0),
    ctx = cv.getContext("2d");

//Paint image using specified width and height
var w = 200,
    h = 200;

var img = $("img").get(0);

img.onload = function() {
    cv.width = w;
    cv.height = h;
    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
};

img.src = "https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/FORD_FOCU_2012-1.png";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="cv"></canvas>
<br>
Original:
<br>
<img>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you've been told is to downscale your image only for the analyses (shape detection).

Your algorithm is probably iterating multiple times over the entirety of the pixels contained in the image searching for patterns.

By reducing the size of the original image, you also reduce the number of pixels to be analyzed, thus improving the performances of the analyze.

You can achieve it quite easily by drawing your original image on a smaller canvas, and by passing only this smaller canvas' ImageData to the analyzer. But obviously, the more you'll shrink your image, the less precision you'll get.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.onload = init;
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';

function init() {
  const ctx = main.getContext('2d');
  main.width = img.width;
  main.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // we'll look for these green squares
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF00FF';
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(Math.random() * img.width, Math.random() * img.height, 10, 10);
  }
// First try with the full Image
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00FF00';
  let t1 = performance.now();
  const big_area = findShapes(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height));
  console.log(`full_size (green) took ${performance.now() - t1}ms`);
  ctx.strokeRect(big_area.x, big_area.y, big_area.width, big_area.height);
  
// Now with the downscaled one
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  t1 = performance.now();
  const area = scaleAndfindShapes(main);
  console.log(`down_sized (blue) took ${performance.now() - t1}ms`);
  ctx.strokeRect(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height);
}

function scaleAndfindShapes(main) {
  // first we create a smaller canvas
  const ratio = main.height / main.width;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio; // max width : 300px

  const scale = main.width / canvas.width;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw the orignal image on this downscaled canvas
  ctx.drawImage(main, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // take the imageData from this smaller canvas
  const img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const rect = findShapes(img);
  // return our bounding rect, rescaled to the main canvas size
  return {
    x: rect.x * scale,
    y: rect.y * scale,
    width: rect.width * scale,
    height: rect.height * scale
  };

}

function findShapes(img) {
  const data = img.data;
  // search for something (here purple pixels)
  const px_indice = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if (data[i] > 254 && data[i + 2] > 254) {
      px_indice.push(i / 4);
    }
  }
  // just build a bounding rect...
  const px_pos = px_indice.map(i => {
    let r = i / img.width,
      y = ~~r;
    return {
      x: Math.round((r - y) * img.width),
      y: y
    };
  });
  const min_x = Math.min.apply(null, px_pos.map(p => p.x));
  const max_x = Math.max.apply(null, px_pos.map(p => p.x));
  const min_y = Math.min.apply(null, px_pos.map(p => p.y));
  const max_y = Math.max.apply(null, px_pos.map(p => p.y));
  return {
    x: min_x,
    width: (max_x - min_x),
    y: min_y,
    height: max_y - min_y
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to do OPs task, when it can be done simply with `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h)`... and I'm not sure that I'm seeing an advantage. Also, how are you pushing to a `const` array?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, yes that"s basically what's done here. But it doesn't prove anything to just do it. Here I made an example that simulate what OP will do, that's why there is more than just what is needed...

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, I'm not sure the comments of this answer are a good place for me to learn you the basics... So in few words : *advantage* : 40ms vs 9ms on my machine for a single pass algo... *`const` array* : only the reference to the object is constant ; the object it references is still mutable.

Comment: Ah, OK. I understand object references, mutability, etc, I've just never seen a `const` array in JS before. In PHP you can definitely ***not*** do this, so that may be one of the other reasons too.

Comment: @Kaiido  this code, is the best way for performance ?

Comment: @yavg no it is not. The best for performance will be device dependant and also relative to what other tasks are running at the same time : it is a Myth. However, this is the easiest way to improve the performances of image analysis, without touching the face detection  algo itself, and it is clearly what you have been told to do.